# Database gear idling

Tags: openshift

I tried searching, but could not find the answer, apologies if my searching skills are not up to the mark.

I am trying to setup an exclusive database gear (free plan on Openshift) with the other 2 gears getting the scalable app (similar to how it is mentioned here  https://blog.openshift.com/how-haproxy-scales-openshift-apps/). I am wondering whether the database gear will be idled after 24 hours because there are no "external connections" to it, as all the connections will be from the other gears. If so should I just create a web interface on the database gear, and manually setup "pings" to the web application?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the DB gear will be idled, however if you are at all worried about your application being idled you should upgrade to a Bronze plan. It is still free if you stay within the same limitations as the free plan, and it is never idled.

Answer (score 1):

Idling is at the application level. You mentioned you had two other gears running alongside the database gear. As long as they get web traffic your database gear will not idle. If you're really worried about idling upgrade to the [Bronze plan](https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing), which disables idling and is still free (assuming you're in a region where Bronze is available).